# There are two MOTD's shown when I login to my server using SSH

Tags: linux, ubuntu, motd

I wanted to change the MOTD that is shown when you login to a computer on a TTY, which seems to work, but somehow, it doesn't just show the MOTD in `/etc/motd` and `/etc/update-motd.d/`, but also another message.

This is shown when I login to my server:

```
sam@laptop:~$ ssh <user>@<server>
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab068.8 i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/
No mail.
Last login: Thu Feb 21 19:20:55 2013 from <ip>
Welcome to Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab068.8 i686)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com/

<user>@<server>:~$
```

My `update-motd.d` contains two files, `00-header` and `10-help-text`.

`00-header` contains the following:

```
[ -r /etc/lsb-release ] && . /etc/lsb-release

if [ -z "$DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION" ] && [ -x /usr/bin/lsb_release ]; then
        # Fall back to using the very slow lsb_release utility
        DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION=$(lsb_release -s -d)
fi

printf "Welcome to %s (%s %s %s)\n" "$DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION" "$(uname -o)" "$(uname -r)"     "$(uname -m)"
```

And `10-help-text` contains this:

```
[ -r /etc/lsb-release ] && . /etc/lsb-release

if [ -z "$DISTRIB_RELEASE" ] && [ -x /usr/bin/lsb_release ]; then
    # Fall back to using the very slow lsb_release utility
    DISTRIB_RELEASE=$(lsb_release -sr)
fi

URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
if uname -r | grep -qs "\-server"; then
    URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/$DISTRIB_RELEASE/serverguide/C"
fi

printf "\n * Documentation:  %s\n" "$URL"
```

This would make up for the portion of the MOTD up until `No mail.`. But where is the rest coming from?

Comment: This should be migrated over to the "ask Ubuntu" folks, as it's quite specific.

Comment: We can't migrate stuff from SF to askubuntu.com

Comment: @GraemeDonaldson Moderators can if they feel it's necessary and a user flags it for their attention. That said, it seems like it's probably fine here as well. If subject matter overlaps between sites, the rule has been to leave it where it was asked.

Comment: Check your shell start-up scripts, both global and user-specific.

Comment: It is not in /etc/profile, ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile and there is no ~/.bash_profile. There is nothing in /etc/profile.d/.

Comment: @MDMarra Oh cool, I didn't realise mods can migrate to sites not in the normal list.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The MOTD can either be printed by `sshd`, or by PAM. It's possible that both are doing it.

Check your `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` for the following:

```
PrintMotd yes
```

If that line isn't present it may be defaulting to `yes` (although Debian/Ubuntu change the default to `no`).

Check your PAM configuration in `/etc/pam.d/` for the following:

```
session    optional     pam_motd.so
```

Try disabling these one at a time to see what changes.

Comment: PAM is out of the question. '-bash: cd: /etc/pam: No such file or directory'

Comment: @SamvanKampen Sorry, `/etc/pam.d/`.

Comment: Ah, I should've checked for that.

Comment: I think this is it, doing cat * | grep motd in pam.d reveals that line. I'll try commenting that and logging in again, if it works, I'll accept your answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Ubuntu, you might try to:

```
sudo nano /etc/ssh/sshd_config
```

and check to see of `PrintMotd` and `UsePam` are both set to true, that was the case for me.

**Note**: Following the above, you can do `sudo service ssh restart` and you should see just one Motd on login.

Comment: Following the above, you can do

sudo service ssh restart

and you should see just one Motd on login.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu 22.04 server, I had this happen by installing the update-motd package. Uninstalling it did not help.

It seems the pam at-login-time dynamic functionality creates `/run/motd.dynamic` and update-motd creates `/run/motd`, and then both gets printed at ssh login.

The solution for me was to uninstall update-motd and remove `/run/motd`:

```
sudo apt remove --purge update-motd
sudo rm -f /run/motd
```

Answer (score 0):

After testing on Debian 8:

It is this option in /etc/pam.d/login prints another motd

```
session    optional   pam_exec.so type=open_session stdout /bin/uname -snrvm
```